# Random Number in julia

Tags: random, julia

I want to make a random number between 1 and 30
I read the document but i can't find a method for do it

for example we do it in php by

```
 rand(1 , 30);
```

How can i handle it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explained in the docs https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand

> #### rand([rng=GLOBAL_RNG], [S], [dims...])
>
> Pick a random element or array of random elements from the set of values specified by S; S can be
>
> - an indexable collection (for example 1:9 or ('x', "y", :z)),
> - an AbstractDict or AbstractSet object,
> - a string (considered as a collection of characters), or
> - a type: the set of values to pick from is then equivalent to typemin(S):typemax(S) for integers (this is not applicable to BigInt), to [0,1)[0, 1)[0,1) for floating point numbers and to [0,1)+i[0,1)[0, 1)+i[0, 1)[0,1)+i[0,1) for complex floating point numbers;

> S defaults to Float64. When only one argument is passed besides the optional rng and is a Tuple, it is interpreted as a collection of values (S) and not as dims.

For your example it would be

```
rand(1:30)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass ranges to the `rand` function to generate a number between two other numbers, included:

```
julia> rand(1:30)
24

julia> rand(1:30)
18
```